# Attempting to run C# on cloud9 IDE but receiving errors

Tags: c#, cloud9-ide, cloud9, c9.io

I’m new to Cloud9 and I’m facing some issues.
I’m attempting to run the C# code on the IDE and am failing to do so, I think I know why but I cant seem to be able to resolve the issue.
The picture uploaded below should have everything needed to solve the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7YJ3.png)

Upon further research, I found a link that goes through a step by step process on how to install .NET core. However, I'm having issues, with setting the project template using this code for the terminal `dotnet new console -lang C#`

It starts decompressing then stops at 99%. (as indicated in image below) The first error that pops up states that `System.IO.IOException: No space left on device` not sure what to do with this though.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkV12.jpg

I kept on attempting the same code and it has managed to complete the decompressing stage only to start resetting again at the Expanding stage. (Refer to image below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErgVT.jpg

Comment: please make sure that you have enough disk space left as dotnet-cli is trying to decompress the downloaded packages, and according to the second image you have taken only 2GB of disk space please opt for more disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Run C# is not yet supported on Cloud9 IDE

https://docs.c9.io/docs/supported-languages

Answer (score 0):

I think @shingo is correct to say C# is not supported BY DEFAULT. It is possible, however, to make it happen as shown in the links below, but not advisable as there is little help out there.  I wouldn't do it if I were you.

[blog help](https://blog.todotnet.com/2017/06/building-net-core-apps-on-cloud9/)
[youtube](https://youtu.be/nUAQHzz_t9k)

[aws documentation not specifically about c# but related](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/build-run-debug.html)